# Unix - how to append next line to previous line in a file

Tags: shell

How can i append the next line to a previous line in a file, delimited by  pipe symbol?

**Expectd Input -- content of input.txt**

```
ABC    
BCD    
DEF    
EFG    
FGH
```

**Expectd Output -- content of output.txt**

```
|ABC|BCD|    
|BCD|DEF|    
|DEF|EFG|    
|EFG|FGH|    
|FGH||
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
paste - - < input-txt
```

is a good start, but it does not add your desired delimiters.  For that, try:

```
 paste - - < input-txt | awk '{$1=$1; print OFS $0 OFS}' OFS=\|
```

(Or any of many other ways to insert the `|` symbol between the fields!  This version emits `|FGH|` instead of `|FGH||` on the final line.)

Or:

```
 sed 1d input-txt | paste -d \| input - | sed 's/^\|$/|/g'
```

Comment: Awesome!! thank you.. I was trying to insert the pipes to the command from your first reply, but you beat me to it. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: hmm just noticed that the output im looking for is 
1|2
2|3
the output from teh command is 
1|2
3|4

Comment: Ah, yes.  For that, try `paste input.txt <(sed 1d input.txt)`

Comment: paste input.txt <(sed 1d input.txt) works perfect. Just used the awk for pipe delimter from teh earlier response.Thanks once again.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Field-Separators.html

```
awk -v ORS="|\n" -v OFS="|" 'NR>1{print p, $1} {p=$1} END{print p, ""}' foo.txt
```

Or without ORS

```
awk -v OFS="|" 'NR>1{print p, $1, ""} {p=$1} END{print p, "", ""}' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

with bash on linux

```
 join -o 1.2,2.2,2.3 -t'|' -1 1 -2 1 -a 1 <(awk '{print(NR"|"$0)}' input.txt | sort -k1,1 -t'|' -n) <(awk '{print(NR - 1"|"$0"|")}' input.txt | sort -k1,1 -t'|' -n)
```

Comment: this seems to hang after printing the first row. I get |ABC|BCD|  and then it just goes to next line and hangs. I hit ^C to exit

Comment: works like a charm at this end on RHEL linux kernel 2.6. What OS are you on?

Comment: In that case all I can offer is sympathy ;-)